# How can I stop myself from printing my terminal

Tags: terminal, printing

I use vscode and terminal all day at work.  It's normal for my terminal to have 10,000+ lines of text.  I am worried I will accidentally print my terminal, and I wonder if there's a way to prevent that from happening.

I think this is pretty likely to happen without some kind of additional safeguards.  In vscode, `cmd+p` is how you open the prompt.  So I frequently hit `cmd+p`, type some text, and then hit enter.  I'm worried I'll accidentally do this in terminal (which would start printing 10k lines of text while I run over and unplug the printer!). I've already opened the print dialog box a few times but luckily have not hit enter.

I think ways to fix this would be 1) an additional step to open the print dialog or 2) a warning if I try to print something huge.

Unfortunately I cannot remove the printer as this is a work machine and I cannot control the printers.

Comment: `this is a work machine and I cannot control the printers` <-- Does this also mean that you cannot add a new printer if you chose to?

Comment: If you can add printers, you could create a fake one and make it the default.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yep, that's where I was headed! :)

Comment: Pressing Cmd-P in Terminal opens the Print dialog, it doesn't print directly. Shouldn't this be enough protection?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but using ⌘ P to get a "prompt" sounds like a pretty terrible choice on vscode's part.  How do you print things in vscode?

Comment: I‘ve been using Macs my entire live and have yet to accidentally print something. This problem seems somewhat artificial.

Comment: @SteveSummit - heh - out of the box VSCode doesn't print _at all!_  You want to print?  Find and install an extension!

Comment: @davidbak Well, I've never used vscode, and I'm not inclined to, either.  Evidently it [can't read input from the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397766/scanf-function-doesnt-work-for-some-reason-any-tip), either. :-\

Comment: Why do you have ten thousand lines of code in a single file in the first place?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The OP said they have 10,000+ lines in their terminal scrollback, not lines of code in a single file. It's pretty common to end up with a scrollback that long if you use a terminal session extensively or kick off a job (like compiling something big) that produces a lot of output.

Comment: This is a complete non-issue. Pressing Command+P does not automatically choose a printer and instruct it to start printing. It opens a dialog asking you how to proceed. *You can just close the dialog.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a custom shortcut for the `print...` menu in Terminal.app. This will overwrite the default shortcut (command-p).

[image]